# Triangular Inequality using Induction

Tags: inequality, induction, recursion

The triangle inequality for absolute value that for all real numbers  *a* and *b*,

[image]

Use the recursive definition of summation, the triangle inequality, the definition of absolute value, and mathematical induction to prove that for all integers n, if

[image]

are real numbers, then

[image]

Please help. I am extremely lost and have no idea where to begin. Any hints will be great. Thank you so very much!

Comment: You probably mean *induction*.

Comment: Yes, my apologies. You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic step: $n = 1$

$|a_1| = |a_1|$.  Done.

Induction step:

Assume $|\sum_{i=1}^k a_i|\le \sum_{i=1}^k|a_i|$. Prove $|\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} a_i|\le \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}|a_i|$

$|\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} a_i| = |(\sum_{i=1}^k a_i) + a_{k+1}|$

By the triangle inequality:

$|(\sum_{i=1}^k a_i) + a_{k+1}| \le |(\sum_{i=1}^k a_i)| + |a_{k+1}|$

we are presuming

$|\sum_{i=1}^k a_i|\le \sum_{i=1}^k|a_i|$

so

$|(\sum_{i=1}^k a_i) | + |a_{k+1}| \le \sum_{i=1}^k|a_i| + |a_{k+1}| = \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}|a_i|$.

So $|\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} a_i|\le \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}|a_i|$

So we have shown $|\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i|\le \sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_i|$ is true for $n = 1$.

We have shown that if $|\sum_{i=1}^n a_i|\le \sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|$ is true for $n =k$ then it is true for $n = k+1$.

So by induction it is true for all natural numbers $n$.

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!